# How to load a html text in to textfield in iOS?

Tags: uiwebview, uitextfield

i am new in iOS development i want to load a html text into textview with one hyper link my text like as

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<p>As the name suggest itself “Trueman India” will cover icons of India. Our national Magazine “Trueman India” is an expansion to our business, it is an addition to our Trueman group of Companies. Trueman group of companies was started initially with the Diamond business with the company name DTC Diamonds and Apple Diamonds in the year 1975. Later with the growth of the company, we entered into entertainment Industry under the banner, “Trueman Entertainment” in the year 2010 and “Trueman Theatres in the year 2012.  Today “TRUEMAN” group of companies consists of Trueman Entertainment, Trueman Theatres and Trueman Foundation which has been our recent discovery. Now we have come with print media called “Trueman India” a National Magazine which will cover Bollywood news, Interviews of Celebrities and some part of it would be dedicated for our real heroes “Policemen” and Politicians. </p><p> If you are interested in advertising on Trueman India, click <a href="http://www.cgim.com/advertise/" target="_safari">here</a> for ad rates and details.  Your input is so important to the success of this site for you and the real true man  around the world. </p>
</body>
</html>
```

i know that UIWebView is better option but when i use it then the hyper link was open in to the same web view not in the safari.i want a link to open into safari 
please give me solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can catch the hyper link click action webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType: and return NO, then open safari for this link